# Reset python path

Tags: python, paths, canopy

I installed canopy and set it to be my default python environment, but I'm having a problem with the software. Now it is:

```
$ which python
/home/renanpc/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python
```

But I need to uninstall canopy and it is necessary to reset the python path to the default, before uninstalling, in (`/usr/bin/python`) and this can't be done in Canopy (due to other problems). How can I do that?

The value of `PATH`:

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/renanpc/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin:
/home/renanpc/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:
/usr/sbin:
/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably want to do is run the command:

```sh
export PATH=":/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

Or probably just `export PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH"` would work, since you probably just need python to be found in that directory before the anaconda directories which are at the start of your path.

This will temporarily remove the undesired paths from `PATH`, and it should find your original python in `/usr/bin`, or you probably move the anaconda directories after `/usr/bin`. Either way, these changes will only persist for the current terminal session. For the changes to `PATH` to persist, you will have to add the command to your .bashrc (or equivalent).

However, I am not sure why you need to do this before uninstalling. If you provide more details I might be able to be of more help.

## Edit:

As the OP points out, Canopy will also add some other cruft to your bash profile on installation, so if you want to get rid of it all, use the command `sudo gedit ~/.bashrc` to edit your profile and remove any line with reference to canopy, (Usually starts with a comment in the prior line saying "added by Canopy Installer").

Comment: I'm not sure this solves my problem since `which python` still points to canopy directory, what changes `export PATH` makes ?

Comment: sorry, apparently you are right, but there is a easier way, I'll mark your answer as right but it'd be useful for future reference if you edit your answer adding this option.  Run `sudo gedit ~/.bashrc` and remove any line with reference to canopy, (Usually starts with a comment in prior line saying "added by Canopy Installer")